# Swift cookie set fails to overwrite existing cookie

Tags: uiwebview, swift3

I have the following code to save cookies but the cookie is not being saved. The get cookie code shows that my cookie is not present in the shared cookies. The "set cookie" is being printed but "get cookie" is not showing my cookie. I can get it to save a new cookie but not overwrite an existing cookie.

```
func setCookie() {

    let infoModel = UserInfoManager.getUserInfoModel()
    if infoModel != nil {

        let ExpTime = TimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)

        let cookieProps: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any] = [

            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: ".mydomain.com",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: "/",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: "DEV",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: infoModel!.userAccessToken!,
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.secure: "TRUE",
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: ExpTime), 
            HTTPCookiePropertyKey.version: "0"                
        ]

        print("WEB REQUEST ACCESS TOKEN \(infoModel!.userAccessToken!)")

        if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: cookieProps) {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)

            print("\(cookie)")

            print("GET COOKIE \(HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies)")

        }
        else {
            print("set cookie failed")
        }

....

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to delete the cookie I wanted to overwrite first.

```
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        if cookie.name == "DEV" {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }             
    }
```